# Performance's difference between for (var x in array) and for (var x=0, y= array.length; x<y; x++)

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

When I want to `loop` through an `array` and add a string behind every `element`,

I can either

```
for(var x in array){
 array[x] += "string";  
}
```

or

```
for(var x, y = array.length; x<y; x++){
 array[x] += "string";  
}
```

But is there **any difference in terms of performance** between these 2 `for loops`?

Comment: For performance check, try http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Note that in both cases you are adding a string to the **index** of each element, which will break the second loop (it's broken anyway since you never initialize `x`).

Comment: did you execute and check the output. It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry I was being a bit careless just now.

Comment: Never use `for … in` to loop through an array, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays

Comment: http://jsperf.com/forinvsfor/5 about 12 times faster in chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [performance difference between for loop and for.. in loop when iterating an array in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9640949/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is recommended that you don't use `for ... in` to iterate over arrays.

i.e. [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

You should use `for ... in` to iterate over object properties only.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, `for...in` is way slower, because it accesses to the array as a common object, while the classic `for` cycle doesn't need to sort out all the properties of `array` to perform its task.

Keep in mind that modern browsers have special optimizations for arrays, but you can't exploit them if you're treating them as common objects.